# constructor defined to take String but method invocation shows error 'Array type expected found java.lang.String'

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have a registration activity which depending on user's selected check boxes, makes an asynchronous call to the server to fetch skills relevant to selected field. I am using retrofit for the same. I have defined a `SQLQuery` class whose constructor takes a String parameter. Now the problem is, when I invoke the constructor with a String argument it shows an error `Array type expected found java.lang.String`. Please someone help me fix this.

Thanks in advance here is my java file

```
package com.example.vishal.internshipseekerapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;



public class StudentRegistration extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final int numFields = 13;
    boolean[] checkField = new boolean[13];
    String[] field = {"computer vision", "content writing", "data mining", "electrical/electronics", "game development", "image processing", "marketing", "mechanical engineering", "mobile app dev", "programming", "software dev", "web dev"};
    Set<Skill> skill = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_registration);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // register onclick listener for all checkboxes
        ( findViewById(R.id.field0)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ( findViewById(R.id.field1)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ( findViewById(R.id.field2)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ( findViewById(R.id.field3)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ( findViewById(R.id.field4)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ( findViewById(R.id.field5)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ( findViewById(R.id.field6)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ( findViewById(R.id.field7)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ( findViewById(R.id.field8)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ( findViewById(R.id.field9)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ( findViewById(R.id.field10)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ( findViewById(R.id.field11)).setOnClickListener(this);
        //( findViewById(R.id.field12)).setOnClickListener(this);

        // register onclick listener for DONE button
        Button done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.field_select_done);
        done.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.field0:
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkField[0] = true;
            case R.id.field1:
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkField[1] = true;
            case R.id.field2:
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkField[2] = true;
            case R.id.field3:
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkField[3] = true;
            case R.id.field4:
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkField[4] = true;
            case R.id.field5:
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkField[5] = true;
            case R.id.field6:
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkField[6] = true;
            case R.id.field7:
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkField[7] = true;
            case R.id.field8:
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkField[8] = true;
            case R.id.field9:
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkField[9] = true;
            case R.id.field10:
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkField[10] = true;
            case R.id.field11:
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkField[11] = true;


            case R.id.field_select_done:
                displayRelevantSkills();
        }
    }

    private void displayRelevantSkills() {
        String field = "field";
        String checkBoxName;


        final String SKILL_FIELD_URL = "https://data.outfight74.hasura-app.io/";


//        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        // set request options for all requests
        Retrofit.Builder builder =
                new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(SKILL_FIELD_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(
                                GsonConverterFactory.create()
                        );

        // create retrofit adapter
        Retrofit retrofit =
                builder
                    /*.client(
                            httpClient.build()
                    )*/
                    .build();

        // create retrofit REST client
        getRelevantSkills skillClient =  retrofit.create(getRelevantSkills.class);

        // for each checkbox do
        for(int i = 0; i < numFields; i++) {
            // if checkbox is ticked
            if(checkField[i]) {
                // fetch relevant skills from server
                SQLQuery skillQuery = new SQLQuery(field[i]);

                Call<List<Skill>> call =
                        skillClient.relevantSkills(skillQuery);

                // Execute the call asynchronously. Get a positive or negative callback.
                call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Skill>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Skill>> call, Response<List<Skill>> response) {
                        // The network call was a success and we got a response
                        // add to skills HashSet
                        skill.addAll(response.body());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Skill>> call, Throwable t) {
                        // the network call was a failure
                        // TODO: handle error
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        // display a drop down menu having all elements of HashSet
        for(Skill s : skill)
        {
            CheckBox skillItem = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            skillItem.setText(s.getSkill());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the `getRelevantSkills.java file`

```
package com.example.vishal.internshipseekerapp;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;


class Where{
    // this will be given by the user
    private String skill;

    public Where(String skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }
}

class Args{
    final String table = "skill_field_relation";
    final String[] columns = {"skill"};
    private Where where;

    public Args(String field) {
        where = new Where(field);
    }
}

class SQLQuery{
    final String type = "select";
    private Args args;
    public SQLQuery(java.lang.String field) {
        args = new Args(field);
    }
}

class Skill{
    private String skill;

    public String getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }

    public Skill(String skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }
}

public interface getRelevantSkills {
    @POST("/v1/query")
    Call<List<Skill>> relevantSkills(
            @Body SQLQuery fetchSkills
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi James, I can see that you are using a Hasura project. Have you tried the Android SDK at https://github.com/hasura/android-sdk ? This might help you build your app faster :)

Comment: @Jaison Titus it would be really good help from your side if you clarify the doubts of your fellow interns regarding android sdk. There is real confusion regarding the social auth module and HasuraUser.socialLoginType() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass `field[i]` to the `SQLQuery` constructor, but `field` is a `String`, not an array. You should pass `field` instead.

EDIT:

```
private void displayRelevantSkills() {
    String field = "field";

    ...

    SQLQuery skillQuery = new SQLQuery(field[i]);
    ...
}
```

You have a local `field` variable of type `String` that hides the instance variable of the same name (whose type is `String[]`).

If you intended to use the instance variable (`String[] field = {...};`), you should write:

```
SQLQuery skillQuery = new SQLQuery(this.field[i]);
```

Comment: looke carefully Sring[] Field = {"some string", "some other string"}; clearly field is a String Array

Comment: @JamesHowlett Look more carefully : `String field = "field";`

Comment: @JamesHowlett Eran is correct. You have shadowed your field. Rename field array to fields to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes you're right. This is shameful actually. Thanks for your help.